# Make PyQt application look like the same on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How can I make a PyQt5 application to look like the same when run on Windows, and Linux?
I would prefer the Windows style on both systems.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using QGuiApplication or QApplication, in other words: widget or not widget based application?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Actually QApplication is widget-based (QGuiApplication isn't, and QCoreApplication is probably what you mean): From the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#details):  _"For non-GUI Qt applications, use QCoreApplication instead, as it does not depend on the Qt GUI module. For QWidget based Qt applications, use QApplication instead, as it provides some functionality needed for creating QWidget instances."_

Comment: @TheCompiler: I am not sure how GUI style would be related to QCoreApplication, nor do I have a clue what you are trying to say to me. :-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp whoops, I'm sorry, I misread indeed. Nevermind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `QApplication::setStyle("windows")` before creating `QApplication` object to set a style by name. However, Qt on Linux is usually built without modern Windows styles, so it's possible that the best you will accomplish is the classic (old) Windows style, which is not very attractive. You can also try to use `"fusion"` style or other values that `QStyleFactory::keys()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing styles mentioned above

or you can specify the styles of your widgets using Stylesheet, which is quite powerful.